# How to handle the authorization required by Google APIs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-people-api

I have basic code for getting google contacts and printing out their information as a desktop application. Currently I do this with OAuth2 to get the access token, etc. But I'm having an issue because I want this to be as automated as possible, and the initial setup requires one to get credentials just to access their contacts. Is there a way around this or a way to automate it? My end goal is to (ideally) be able to put in a users email address and be able to get their contacts, without them ever having to go through the developer's console. I know they only have to do it once, but it can be a pain for users who don't understand.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way to automate this as Google Contact API requires an authorized request. For detailed information about flows for various types of applications, see Google's [OAuth 2.0 documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2.html). Just try to create a user friendly authorizing procedure for a workaround. Hope this helps.

Comment: And theres no way to use the old way of doing things, OAuth1, etc?

Comment: The Google Contacts API was deprecated. Nowadays you might use the People API but the title should not be about the API but about how to make it easier for users to handle the authorization. If you are still looking for an answer for this, you should add more details.... is this some sort of open source project? do you don't want to have to deal with the API billing?